# Show that $b \in N(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}))$ if and only if $b' \in N(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}))$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Consider a quadratic form $f= z^2 - ax^2 - by^2$ ; $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $bb' = t^2 - a$ for some $b'$. Then I need to show that $b \in N(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}))$ if and only if $b' \in N(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}))$.

Here, $N(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}))$ denoted the group of norms of the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})$. This norm is defined as $N(u + v\sqrt{a}) = (u + v\sqrt{a})(u - v\sqrt{a}) = u^2 - av^2$

Therefore, (for $\Rightarrow$), I can express $b$ as equal to $u^2 - av^2$ ($u,v \in \mathbb{Q}$). So, $$(u^2 - av^2)b' = t^2 - a$$
But from this I am not able to express $b'$ as equal to some $x^2 - ay^2$ ($x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$). Any help here!

I suppose the other direction $\Leftarrow$ is also somewhat similar. So can anyone help me in proving $\Rightarrow$ ?

Comment: What is $t$ in "$bb'=t^2-a$"?

Comment: It's a rational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $t^2-a=N(t+\sqrt a)$ where $t+\sqrt a\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt a)$. If $b=N(z)$ for some $z\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt a)$ then
$$
b'=\frac{t^2-a}{b}=\frac{N(t+\sqrt a)}{N(z)}=N(\frac{t+\sqrt a}{z}).
$$
Because $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt a)$ is a field we have $(t+\sqrt a)/z\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt a)$.

Comment: Exceptions come if it is possible that $b=0$ (when $z=0$ also). However, then $t=\pm\sqrt a$ and you won't have an extension field at all, so I suspect that this possibility can be dismissed.

Comment: Thank you. Here how do I show the norm equality $\frac{N(a)}{N(b)} = N(\frac{a}{b})$?

Comment: Let $\sigma$ be the automorphism $\sigma(u+v\sqrt a)=u-v\sqrt a$. Because it is an automorphism we have $$\sigma(zz')=\sigma(z)\sigma(z')$$ for all $z,z'\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt a)$.  If you haven't covered automorphisms yet you can also easily check that property directly. Then you have $N(z)=z\sigma(z)$, and the rest follows. Observe that this is totally similar to the game with the usual complex conjugation: $\overline{z_1z_2}=\overline{z_1}\cdot \overline{z_2}$, $N(z)=z\cdot \overline{z}$ etc.